# Comment author name issue

Tags: wordpress

I tried to test the blog section on my website, when I tried to add a new comment to the blog, I filled the fields of message, name and email address,
after I pressed submit I saw the comment, but the name of the comment’s author was not the name when I filled before.

The name of all the comments is the value of “Display name publicly as” in the users section in the dashboard.

How can I change that the name of the comment’s author will be shown and not the anything else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please see: [this relevant code in WordPress core](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/339d8384755f0355c076fb7cf2e299cce79bd453/wp-includes/comment.php#L3085-L3101). If you are logged into the site when posting a comment, the name is forced to the user name as you've seen in your tests.

So the answer to your question is that you need to logout before posting.

Comment: I logged out and it still takes the name of "Display name publicly as"

Comment: @user3561607 Try clearing your cookies, because sometimes you're logged in on both `http://` and `https://`, or from an older WordPress installation on another primary domain as the one you currently have. Just try to rule that out and confirm that you are in fact logged-out entirely.